# Database with ionic

Tags: angularjs, rest, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

We are 2 students studying web development.
Right now we are researching and trying to figure out a solution for an ionic app.

the app will have a lot of data content (video, image, music etc)

The questions are: should the APP be developed with a REST api? (seems like the only/best way to connect to a database with ionic?)

or can you build the app with a cloud-based-database without the REST-api  (any suggestion for the database?)

and last should we use LocalStorage as our database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me go from bottom to top; if you said you'll use a lot of content in your database - don't even think about local storage. If you really *must* have a local database as well, consider looking into SQLite (https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage).

The sentence "cloudbased-database without the REST api" honestly makes no sense in Ionic. Let me explain; Ionic uses Angular as its front-end framework. And, **front-end** is the key word here. You can take any front end framework, or pure vanilla JavaScript for that matter and you will **not** be able to connect to any database (be it in the cloud, locally, or whereever). It's just not how that's suppose to work.

So, finally, to confirm - yes, you will have to create a (REST) API for your database which will then allow you to "talk to" the database with Ionic.

Hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: Nikola! thank you for the anwer on this matter, this is a big help for us! We can now proceed with the proper solution in our mind.

Comment: No problem, glad I helped. Good luck guys!